# Jmeter multiple same Requests

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I could somehow run JMeter test for a user but running HTTP requests a few time such like (multiple users). The problem is that authentication only supports one session and I don't think it's ok to create 50 users in LDAP to be able to test. I tried to use 'Parallel Controller' but after executing the first request the others have the status 'Socket closed'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't think it's ok to create 50 users in LDAP to be able to test

I think this is what you should be really doing.

Parallel Controller is a kind of workaround to bypass JMeter Threads Model limitation when it comes to implementing specific test scenarios like simulating [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) requests because it assumes several requests executing in parallel triggered by a single thread (virtual user)

In the majority of cases user does sequential actions like open login page -> login -> navigate somewhere -> type something -> etc.

Ideally each JMeter thread (virtual user) must represent a real user with unique credentials so I would strongly recommend either creating as many users as you need to simulate in LDAP, if you're not allowed to have test users in LDAP on permanent basis you can even create them from JMeter like:

- [setUp Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) - create users
- normal Thread Group with your main test actions
- [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) - delete users

See [How to Load Test LDAP with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ldap-apache-jmeter) article to learn more about different types of LDAP requests you can send from JMeter

Comment: thanks for the idea with setUp Thread Group:
I created a setUP Thread Group(I logged in with a user);
I saved the session properties in a global JMeter variable;
Then I create the Thread Group and from the beginning of the execution I extract the information from the global JMeter variables;
Set how many users I need in the Group thread